# Why is this code slow?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have the following code which is used to encode byte array to HEX string

```
private static final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
public static void WriteHexBytes(byte[] data, StringBuilder sb)
{
    char[] chars = new char[data.length*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
        chars[2*i] = HEX_CHARS[(data[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
        chars[2*i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[data[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    sb.append(chars);
}
```

The `for` loop is very slow, it takes about `10 seconds` to encode `3MB` of bytes on real device. On the emulator it takes like forever.
The `sb.append` is performed instantly.

Is this normal? It seems very slow to me? What is causing slowness?

Tested on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0

Comment: have a look at this. http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/04/16/converting-a-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-in-java-and-android-2/

Comment: I mean, even running an loop with 'chars[x] = 0;' takes like two seconds???

Comment: after decoding do you want to upload any webservice ?

Comment: Yes, when I encode bytes, I send them to web service

Comment: Use left shift instead of `2*i`. Extract `2*i` expression to the local variable.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java

Comment: @Rafael: Nonsense. Don't spread bullshit without the appropriate warning: "I'll just tell you random stuff, but I'm actually not sure it's true." I hope that you aren't sure -- because you're wrong.

Comment: @nes do not need to be rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious that there is a faster approach than what you show, from a Java perspective. [Apache Common's code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.7/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.java#Hex.encodeHex%28byte%5B%5D%29) looks slightly better than yours, but that's really just a vague guess.

From here on, if you need more, you'll just have to Microbenchmark on your hardware, I'm afraid :(.

Just out of idleness … I did micro benchmark (ad-hoc, unscientific) your solution and one I just cooked up -- you win by a factor of two. Here's what I tried:

```
public static void niko(byte[] data, StringBuilder sb)
{
    for (byte element : data) {
        sb.append(toChar((element & 0xf0) >>> 4));
        sb.append(toChar(element & 0x0f));
    }
}

static char toChar(int b) {
    int offset = b < 10 ? 48 : 87;
    return (char) (b + offset);
}
```

Going thru 10 MB 100 times, your code completes in 4 seconds, mine in 8. But keep in mind that this is very hardware dependent, JVM-dependenect, etc.

Comment: Wow! Which hardware or device? Your results are more than 100x better than mine!
On my Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, Android 4.1 for 3MB just 1 time takes between 5 and 10 seconds???
I would expect that code is slower on mobile device, but hundreds of times slower??? What is wrong?
Just the simple for loop from 1..3M takes 2 seconds to complete... This speed is like on 40MHz Intel 386 or even worse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to write this as a comment (can't try whether this makes a difference on Android), but I can't write formatted code in comments... :-/

You could try caching some values to avoid some invokations:

```
int len = data.length;
char[] chars = new char[len * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    int b = data[i] & 0xff;
    chars[2*i] = HEX_CHARS[b >>> 4];
    chars[2*i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[b & 0x0F];
}
```

p.s.

If returning a String instead of writing to StringBuilder is fine, you could also try to write to a byte array instead of a char array to reduce the allocated memory size, then construct the string from the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion:

```
public static void writeHexBytes(byte[] data, StringBuilder sb) {
    for (byte b : data) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
}
```